# How does OpenLayers determine a layer's projection?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

Could anyone explain the strategy OpenLayers take to determine the layer's projection?

For example, if I didn't explicitly specify any projection for a marker layer, what projection would the layer take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify a projection the projection will be null (undefined) - when the layer is added to the map it will [inherit the map's projection](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer.js#L609).

This is easily verified with the following code:

```
aLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers();
alert("Projection : " + aLayer.projection);     // Projection: null
map.addLayer(aLayer);
alert("Projection after adding to map: " + aLayer.projection);  // Projection: EPSG: 900913
```